# Redirecting directory without slash to directory with slash and https

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect address:

```
http://example.com/blog
```

to address:

```
https://example.com/blog/
```

Take into account that, I'm trying to redirect from NO HTTPS to HTTPS.

So far, I achieved the desired result in 2 redirects. I want to achieve it in one redirect.

I need also to mention, that `blog` is a physical directory.

I'm using this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/blog/ [R=301,L]
```

It redirects from `http://example.com/blog/` (no-HTTPS) to `https://example.com/blog/` (HTTPS).

And it is `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the `.htaccess` file you are referring to is in the document root? ie. `example.com/.htaccess`?

> It redirects from `http://example.com/blog/` (no-HTTPS) to `https://example.com/blog/` (HTTPS)

Maybe this is just a "typo", but... it doesn't. Your `RewriteRule` directive explicitly includes the `www` subdomain.

> I achieved the desired result in 2 redirects.

Well, the code you posted is just one redirect, not two. So, where is the other redirect coming from? Ordinarily, mod_dir will trigger an implicit redirect from `http://example.com/blog` to `http://example.com/blog/` if `blog` is a physical directory (which you say it is). However, the directive(s) you posted should override this behaviour, unless...

... You have another `.htaccess` file in the `/blog` subdirectory that uses mod_rewrite? If you have a WordPress *blog* in the `/blog` subdirectory then this is quite probable. If this is the case then your mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` are being completely ignored - they aren't doing anything! (Which, incidentally, would explain why you have `www.example.com` in your `RewriteRule` directive but are seeing a redirect to `example.com` - although maybe that is just a "typo"? Please clarify.)

As mentioned, mod_dir will implicitly trigger a 301 redirect from `/blog` to `/blog/` and then maybe WordPress itself is triggering the redirect from HTTP to HTTPS? That's your two redirects. Admittedly that's a bit of a guess, but without more information, that's all we can do. What does the network traffic report? Specifically, what redirects are you seeing?

### Solution

If the above hypothesis is correct that it's a bit of a tough one! You could get around the double redirect by moving everything from `/blog/.htaccess` into the parent `.htaccess` file (and making the necessary adjustments). However, this might *break* WordPress to some extent - as WP will no longer be able to maintain the `.htaccess` file.

Alternatively, if you are on Apache 2.4+ then you can mess with `DirectorySlash Off` and `RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash` and move your directives into the `/blog/.htaccess` file. Although I kinda wonder whether this is really "worth it"?

**UPDATE:** For example, as mentioned above, you can move your redirect into the `/blog/.htaccess` file (near the top) and turn `DirectorySlash Off` and set `RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash` - this requires Apache 2.4+:

```
# Prevent mod_dir implicitly appending a slash on directories (via redirect)
DirectorySlash Off

# Allow mod_rewrite to function when there is no trailing slash
RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash

# Redirect http://example.com/blog to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/blog/ [R=301,L]
```

This should do as you require - in a single redirect. However, I've modified your redirect to include requests for `https://www.example.com/blog` (ie. HTTPS + `/blog` no trailing slash), otherwise that will no longer be resolved correctly - presumably this is a requirement?

Also, your existing redirect does not redirect `http://www.example.com/blog/<something>` - presumably that is intentional?

As with all 301 redirects, your browser cache will need to be cleared before testing.

You should also note that with `DirectorySlash Off`, mod_dir will not append the trailing slash to *any* subdirectories - should they be accessed. You will need to manage this as required. This can result in "unexpected behaviour", which I think is the biggest concern. Test test test.

AFAIK the only **security** concern is if you have directory indexes enabled. So, to be sure, these should be disabled: `Options -Indexes` in your `.htaccess` file. See the [DirectorySlash directive in the Apache Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) for more information.

Comment: You're absolutly righht. I have 2 htaccess files. One in root directory , one in blog (subdirectory). In roots' htacess I've rules that do not apply to redirects I need (vide from blog with no slash and no https, to blog with slash and https on). In blogs' htacess I've rules that apply to redirects I need (blog is a wordpress one).

Comment: As I've mentioned I need redirect from addres http://example.com/blog to address https://example.com/blog/. Even better would be redirect to address https://www.example.com/blog/ It doesn't need to be oneliner in htaccess. If I use DirectorySlash Off and RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash would that be a security concern?
I'll accept your answer, cause it's the closest to what I need.

Comment: Btw. www in an address is desired prefix. So it's all ok, not a typo.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example and concerns about `DirectorySlash Off`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you meant 'one line' or 'one redirect' (or rewrite in your case). Since you already have only one RewriteRule, I assumed that you are aiming for a one-liner:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/blog/?$ https://example.com/blog/ [R=301,L]
```

That rewrites every HTTP-request that starts with /blog and either ends there or has a 'trailing slash' to https://example.com/blog/

Comment: That rule doesn't work if blog is directory and htaccess is withing blog subdirectory, that this rule applies to.